# Return flight is 31 days after arrival, Egypt visa-on-arrival is 30 days, will I be allowed to board?

Tags: tourist-visas, egypt, german-citizens

I have a return ticket from Germany (Frankfurt) to Egypt (Cairo). The return date is 31 days after the arrival date.

The tourist visa-on-arrival is 30 days for German citizens.

Presently my plan is not to apply for a 90 day tourist visa before hand.

I intend leaving Egypt via Sudan overland.

I do not know how long I will be in Egypt. My plan was to extend my visa in Egypt if this is necessary.

I am flying Egypt Air.

**Questions**

1. Will I be allowed to board the aircraft without a visa?
2. Or should I get a 90 day visa before departure?
3. Or should I change the return date of my ticket which costs money :( ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German passport holders can get a 30-day visa on arrival provided they have a return ticket that shows that the person will leave Egypt within 30 days. It will totally depend on the visa officer and there is a chance that you might be denied entry in Egypt.

Your best bet is to either get a 90-day visa if you plan to use your already booked return ticket or book a new ticket with the return date within 30 days of your arrival and cancel it later if you plan to extend your stay.